# Akka actors and shared data: thead-safe, thread-unsafe, or ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, thread-safety, akka, actor, thread-local

Say I have several `UntypedActor` classes that each get `FizzBuzz` references:

```
class FooActor extends UntypedActor {
    FizzBuzz fizzBuzz

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        // whatever...
    }
}

class BarActor extends UntypedActor {
    FizzBuzz fizzBuzz

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        // whatever...
    }
}
```

If both are injected with the **same instance** of `FizzBuzz`, then:

Can each actor both read and write to `fizzBuzz` in a thread-safe manner? Meaning, can `FooActor` write a change to `fizzBuzz` that will then be immediately seen over in `BarActor`? Or does Akka provide each actor instance its own `ThreadLocal` copy?

Also, same question as above, but for multiple instances of the same actor class (e.g. if there are 10 `FooActors`, etc.).

Comment: Different `FizzBuzz` references or the same one?

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1) - yes, I forgot the most important part: all actors are sharing the *same* instance. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Then you have no thread safety. This breaks Akka. You should look into [Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html). But, ideally, use immutable objects.

Comment: You didn't mention whether `FizzBuzz` was immutable or not. If it is, you're fine. If it isn't, you are potentially in trouble, depending what you do with it.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1 for both). No `FizzBuzz` is not immutable, in reality it is a dynamic config object holding configs fed to it in real-time from [Consul](https://www.consul.io/). So each actor needs to dynamically know when Consul pushes a config change "down" to them. Because its a config object (say, holding the URI for a particular 3rd party API), I'm OK with it not being thread-safe. What does worry me if when you say "*This breaks Akka.*" Were you just exaggerating here, or will this literally bring Akka to its knees? Thanks again!